# iOS: Strange warnings and strange back on second select on table view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am having a strange warning when I segue to one of my ViewControllers. Here is the warning:

```
Action connections from <UIView: 0x792b2a0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x79e1ad0>> are not supported.
```

An other problem is, I am using a second UITableView to select a value from a list as dropdown list. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I am doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.tergetTextField.text = self.items[indexPath.row];
    [self performSelector:@selector(returnToParent) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}

- (void) returnToParent {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

When I select a value from UITableView I am getting following warning:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <HMXSelectViewController: 0x7bb0350>
```

I have seen similar questions about this warning but given solutions did not worked for me. "performSelector afterDelay" was one of the solution adviced.

And the last strange problem is when I seque to UITableView for second time it returns after second time I select an item not on first.

Here is my codes: http://pastebin.com/TVn51ppD

And as a side question, what would you advice for selecting an item between 3 to 5 items, like a dropdown list?

**UPDATE:**
I have solved the `Unbalanced calls` and return on second select on UITableView problems with following:

```
- (IBAction)scaleEditingDidBegin:(id)sender {
    selectionSource = 0;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"select" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)statusEditingDidBegin:(id)sender {
    selectionSource = 1;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"select" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for*` error is, when user touches UITextField, in `scaleEditingDidBegin` or `statusEditingDidBegin` function whe go to other UIView before `Editing Did End` event fired. To fix this add `[self.view endEditing:YES]` to both functions:

```
- (IBAction)scaleEditingDidBegin:(id)sender {
    selectionSource = 0;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"select" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)statusEditingDidBegin:(id)sender {
    selectionSource = 1;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"select" sender:self];
}
```